# Evaluating the Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y} dxdy$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to find ,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+y)}}{x+y} dxdy$$

My attempt:

I tried doing integration wrt x first then substitute $t = x+y$,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x+y} dx\right) dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} \left( \int_{t=y}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(t-y)}}{t} dt\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}   \int_{t=y}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt  
$$

I don't know how to proceed further. Any hint on how should i tackle this kind of problem would be appreciated ...

Comment: Try $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}   \int_{y=0}^{y=t} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dy\,dt  
$$

Comment: Okay. Change of integration it is. Got it. Thank you @Did Answer is $1$.